# How to convert csv to xls in informatica

Tags: csv, xls, informatica

I have informatica ETL reside in linux server. My client requirement is to generate xls file using informatica and If the data is more than 65k then I need to create another sheet in until I populate the data. Is this possible? How?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you should use Informatica to convert CSV to Excel. Use CSV as output, use a separate tool/script to do the CSV->XLS conversion. If CSV is the only source, don't involve Informatica at all.

Answer (score 0):

Excel output is not natively supported in Informatica. Although it can be done using Java transformation with [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) libraries for Excel.

Comment: hi samik appreciate taking time my question. do you have linkon step by step procedure in using java transformation to output in xls using csv as source.  Thank you.